# Nodejs child process and SIGKILL

Tags: node.js, process, signals, sigkill

I am looking for a way to kill all child processes spawned when my parent process die (including by receiving SIGKILL).

PM2 process manager seems to have the key, because sending a SIGKILL to pm2 Daemon causes all child processes to exit (on Linux platform).

So do you know how PM2 achieve this ? how can I reproduce this behavior ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

```
'use strict'

const { fork } = require('child_process')

// fork a child process
const child = fork('new_process.js')

// when the main process exits, send the kill signal to the child process
process.on('exit', (code) => {
  console.log(`About to exit with code: ${code}`)
  child.kill(9)
})
```

Usefull docs

[NodeJS - Child Process - kill()](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_kill_signal)

[NodeJS - Process - exit event](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_exit)

Comment: Thanks ! And if my parent process receives a SIGKILL, is there a way to kill child similarly ?

Comment: You can specify `process.on('SIGKILL', () => { child.kill(); process.exit(); }) `

Comment: Other info on manageable signals [here](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_signal_events)

Comment: A process can't listen on SIGKILL event

Comment: Interestinf info here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30708801/node-js-child-processes-being-killed-when-parent-dies - seems that the child will die always with default settings

Comment: Thanks for the link, I have tested multiple spawn configurations but unfortunately child remains alive when parent is killed with SIGKILL, so I think it is just impossible to achieve what I want

Comment: Is surely possibile, but it depends on the software design and node version