# How do spawned child processes behave when a Node app is stopped

Tags: node.js, child-process, spawn

When ending a Node app using ctrl + c in the windows command line. What happens to spawned child processes. Are these terminated as well?

Comment: you'll find your answer here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30708801/node-js-child-processes-being-killed-when-parent-dies)

Comment: @AlokDeshwal thanks for pointing me to that topic. I marked my question as a dupicate.